# TinyMCE loading issue on rails admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I have used TinyMCE editor for the textarea field on Rails Admin. I am using 'rails_admin', '~> 2.2.1' gem. TinyMCE configuration file is given below:

app/assets/javascripts/rails_admin/custom/ui.js

```
//= require tinymce
    
    var admin = {
        initTinyMce: function() { tinyMCE.init({ selector: 'textarea',
            height: 500,
            menubar: false,
            toolbar: 'undo redo  blocks fontfamily fontsize  bold italic underline strikethrough alignleft aligncenter alignright lineheight link image media table mergetags checklist numlist bullist indent outdent removeformat help',
            plugins: 'insertdatetime lists media table code help wordcount image link anchor autolink'
        }) }
    }
    
    $(function() {
        admin.initTinyMce();
    
        $(document).on('rails_admin.dom_ready', function() {
            admin.initTinyMce();
        });
    });
```

config/tinymce.yml

```
selector: 'textarea'
height: 500
menubar: false
toolbar:
  - undo redo | blocks fontfamily fontsize | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright lineheight | link image media table mergetags | checklist numlist bullist indent outdent | removeformat | help
plugins:
  - insertdatetime lists media table code help wordcount image link anchor autolink
```

Sometimes TinyMCE is not loaded in rails admin. It loads the default editor. However, when I refresh the page it loads the TinyMCE editor perfectly. What is the solution to that issue? Another thing is how can I use the config/tinymce.yml configuration for the rails admin?